# PHP - conversion object to array - empty array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to convert an object to an array but I always end up with an empty array.

The object is the following:

```
DOMElement Object
(
[tagName] => span
[schemaTypeInfo] => 
[nodeName] => span
[nodeValue] => 
[nodeType] => 1
[parentNode] => (object value omitted)
[childNodes] => (object value omitted)
[firstChild] => 
[lastChild] => 
[previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
[nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
[attributes] => (object value omitted)
[ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
[namespaceURI] => 
[prefix] => 
[localName] => span
[baseURI] => 
[textContent] => 
)
```

This object is store in $my_object

If I try this:

```
$test = get_object_vars($my_object);
print_r($test);
```

I get an empty array.

If I try this:

```
$test = (array)$my_object;
print_r($test);
```

I also get an empty array

If I try this:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($my_object), true);
```

Same result, empty array.

Am I doing something wrong ? Seemed fairly simple but I don't find a way to convert my object into an array.

Any idea?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: Now explain us - why do you do this?

Comment: The data needs to feed another array so either I turn the object into an array or I take every individual sub object to store then in my other array (would take more code I guess)

Comment: It's a strange approach to move DOM object elsewhere.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm collecting data from multiple sources (json, xml, dom,...) and aggregate it into one array. So I basically need some of the data of this object to add it into my big array.

Comment: And what data do you need? Why you just can't extract what you need from `DOMElement Object` and put it into your array?